# Error while installing chefdk in to the windows

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to install chefdk in Windows OS and while running knife command in command prompt I am getting the following error:

> "C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.14.89-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/application/knife.rb:212:in
>   `print_help_and_exit': private method 'list_commands' called for
>   Chef::Knife:Class (NoMethodError) Did you mean?  subcommands"

Can someone please help me out in rectifying this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please report bugs to the ChefDK GitHub project at https://github.com/chef/chef-dk/issues/new. StackOverflow is for help requests, not bug reports.

Comment: Thanks for helping me on this